# Converting HTML table to dictionary with beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, html-table, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to convert a table of this format to a dictionary and having more trouble than I should.

The table is of this format:

```
 <table class="grid">
    <tbody><tr class="tableheading">
        <td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A value</td><td>B value</td><td>C value</td><td>D value</td><td>E value</td><td>F Value</td><td>G value</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to make it to a dictionary which would be like

```
foo["A":"A Value", "B":"B value" ...]
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It would help if you posted some code that you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this, explicitly selecting the class you want, on the table row, for the keys and the class you want (None) for values.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html  ="""
<table class="grid">
    <tbody><tr class="tableheading">
        <td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A value</td><td>B value</td><td>C value</td><td>D value</td><td>E value</td><td>F Value</td><td>G value</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
keys =[i.text for i in soup.find('tr', {'class': 'tableheading'}).find_all('td')]
vals = [i.text for i in soup.find('tr', {'class': None}).find_all('td')]
my_dict = dict(zip(keys, vals))
print (my_dict)
```

Outputs:

```
{'F': 'F Value', 'C': 'C value', 'D': 'D value', 'E': 'E value', 'G': 'G value', 'A': 'A value', 'B': 'B value'}
```

Comment: This code would break if there were multiple tables on the page since it doesn't target any one particular table.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
... 
... soup = BeautifulSoup("""\
...  <table class="grid">
...     <tbody><tr class="tableheading">
...         <td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td>
...     </tr>
...     <tr>
...         <td>A value</td><td>B value</td><td>C value</td><td>D value</td><td>E value</td><td>F Value</td><td>G value</td>
...     </tr>
...     </tbody>
... </table>
... """, 'lxml')
... 
... result = {}
... table = soup.find('table', class_='grid')
... for header, value in zip(*(tr.find_all('td') for tr in table.find_all('tr'))):
...     result[header.text] = value.text
... 
>>> result
{'A': 'A value', 'B': 'B value', 'C': 'C value', 'D': 'D value', 'E': 'E value', 'F': 'F Value', 'G': 'G value'}
```